# Deep object serialization in Java

Tags: java, json

I have the class

```java
public class PlayerData {

  public boolean hasIsland = false;
  public int genProgress = 0;
  public SimpleLoc islandLocation = null;

  ...

}
```

I want to serialize it to JSON:

```java
public class PlayerData {
  ...

  public String serialize() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
  }

}
```

This only serializes the hasIsland and genProgress fields. How can I make islandLocation serialize too?

I mean deep serialization. I don't want to manually serialize class fields.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-deep-clone-using-serializable.html).  Note: site's SSL certificate expired 8 days ago, but it should still be safe.

Answer (score 1):

If by "deep serialization" you mean that deserialization will result in a deep copy of the object, then deep serialization is inherent in object serialization (and can be achieved by manual serialization).
Otherwise, please clarify what is meant by "deep serialization".

Google's `Gson` library is awesome and supports lots of customization to solve issues exactly like yours: simply replace `new Gson()` with `new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()`